# Is it possible to upload an ASP.NET web application onto a virtual 2008 server on VMware?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, mysql, html, css

Is it possible to upload an ASP.NET web application onto a virtual 2008 server on VMware?
After creating a web application from visual studios, I am trying to upload it onto a virtual server.
Can it be done? If possible is there any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Doing it inside VMware is no different from doing it on a regular machine.

First you just do your normal release build in Visual Studio so your bin directory has your web application ready to go. Then you can deploy in either one of two ways:

1. Use the automated deployment tool inside visual studio (Build -> Publish)
2. Use the IIS Server Management tool to create your application on the machine, and upload the files for your web application (either via FTP, or just copy+paste with remote desktop) to the directory you specified to contain the application.